# How get multiple SUM() for different columns with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

This is what I've got:

```
SELECT     
    SUBJECT_ID, SUM(SOMETABLE.COLUMN) AS HOURS, POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM       
    SOME_TABLES
WHERE     
    (GROUP = (SELECT TOP (1) GROUP
              FROM SOMETABLE2
              WHERE (STUDENT_ID = 123)))
GROUP BY 
    SUBJECT_ID, POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
HAVING      
    (SUBJECT_ID = 782)
```

This query returns:

[image]

I need to get this result:

[image]

To get that results I'm using this query:

```
SELECT     
    SUBJECT_ID, SUM(SOMETABLE.COLUMN) AS HOURS,  
    SUM(SOMETABLE3.COLUMN) AS POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM
    SOME_TABLES
WHERE     
    (GROUP = (SELECT TOP (1) GROUP
              FROM SOMETABLE2
              WHERE (STUDENT_ID = 123)))
GROUP BY 
    SUBJECT_ID, SEMESTER_ID
HAVING      
    (SUBJECT_ID = 12)
```

But it returns `SUM` without including `GROUP BY` statement - like on second screenshot but there is 16 points two times, while there should be two rows with 8 points per semester.

How to get correct POINTS to SEMESTER_ID? There is script with sample data
 in comment under this post.

Comment: Give us some sample data to work with...

Comment: You're summing up a `SOMETABLE3.COLUMN` which isn't shown in your query anywhere...

Comment: Add `where points > 0`.  If that isn't what you want, try explaining the logic you *do* want for the query.

Comment: Sample data: http://pastebin.com/F0sNc8PW

Comment: @MarcinSz. what is the connection between STUDENT_ID and the sample data provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**OVER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause, something like:

**QUERY**

```
select distinct 
       Id,
       sum(Hours) over (partition by SimId) Hours,
       sum(Points) over (partition by SimId) Points,
       SimId  
from #t
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
    Id INT,
    Hours INT,
    Points INT, 
    SimId INT
)

insert into #t values
(787,100,0,214858),
(787,0,8,214858),
(787,100,8,233562),
(787,0,0,233562)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id  Hours   Points  SimId
787 100     8       214858
787 100     8       233562
```

**UPDATE**

That because you not provided sample data you can do with `CTE` in following:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT     
    SUBJECT_ID, SUM(SOMETABLE.COLUMN) AS HOURS,  
    SUM(SOMETABLE3.COLUMN) AS POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM
    SOME_TABLES
WHERE     
    (GROUP = (SELECT TOP (1) GROUP
              FROM SOMETABLE2
              WHERE (STUDENT_ID = 123)))
GROUP BY 
    SUBJECT_ID, SEMESTER_ID
HAVING      
    (SUBJECT_ID = 12)
)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_ID,
       sum(Hours) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID) Hours,
       sum(Points) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID) Points,
       SEMESTER_ID  
FROM cte
```

**UPDATE 2**

You can create `#temp_table` and insert data from your select query, after It use `CTE` in following:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT * 
FROM #temp_table
)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_ID,
       sum(Hours) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID) Hours,
       sum(Points) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID) Points,
       SEMESTER_ID  
FROM cte
```

Comment: #t is a temp table defined in the "Sample Data" portion of his answer.  Looks like it is filled with sample data from OP's post.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm trying to run this query i receive: `Column 'cte.HOURS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` Without group by i receive some results without errors.

Comment: I've tried with updated version. Problem is probably in primary query because when I'm using my [sample data](http://pastebin.com/HnEyRXmL) everything works fine: http://pokaz.im/di-T8PS.png
Table "SAMPLE_TABLE" is created from `Select * into SAMPLE_TABLE from PRIMARY_TABLE`, whitch looks like this `SELECT     
    SUBJECT_ID, SOMETABLE.COLUMN AS HOURS, POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM       
    SOME_TABLES and some inner joins
WHERE     
    (GROUP = (SELECT TOP (1) GROUP
              FROM SOMETABLE2
              WHERE (STUDENT_ID = 123)))`

Comment: @MarcinSz. So second query works for you? If It works, accept It as correct answer.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas It works only when I create table "[SAMPLE_TABLE](http://pastebin.com/HnEyRXmL)" from `Select * into SAMPLE_TABLE from SOME_TABLES`. By `SOME_TABLES` I mean data from [this query](http://pokaz.im/di-ODSDKWVT.png). When I put original query directly into new query it doesn't work but when I put SAMPLE_TABLE created from original query it magically works.

Comment: Try to remove `SUM` and `GROUP BY` from `INNER QUERY` (CTE)

Comment: With removed `SUM` and `GROUP BY` from `INNER QUERY`: http://pokaz.im/di-P3ZB.png
Without `SUM` in `OUTER QUERY`: http://pokaz.im/di-XQWT.png

Comment: Try to remove `SUM` from `POINTS` now, try playing around.

Comment: Without `SUM` from `POINTS`: http://pokaz.im/di-08TW.png
Without `SUM` from `HOURS`: http://pokaz.im/di-N7PR.png

Comment: So how about to create `#temp_table`, after it `INSERT INTO #temp_table (col1, col2...) SELECT col1, col2 FROM [Your_Query]` And after It use `CTE` solution from my answer? (Updated again)

Comment: Sample data: http://pastebin.com/XRxFMn17
Workflow and results: http://pokaz.im/di-9LX3.png, http://pokaz.im/di-SEQF.png, http://pokaz.im/di-JTB2.png, http://pokaz.im/di-I2GG.png

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Finaly I've got working query! http://pokaz.im/di-TEE7.png
It doesn't work without `GROUP BY` inside `INNER QUERY`: http://pokaz.im/di-HVXH.png
Why this `GROUP BY` inside `INNER QUERY` is so important? Maybe it's for new thread ;) Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
     SUBJECT_ID,SEMESTER)ID
    ,SUM(HOURS) as HOURS
    ,SUM(POINTS) as POINTS
FROM SOME_TABLES
WHERE SUBJECT_ID = 12
GROUP BY
     SUBJECT_ID,SEMESTER)ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `CROSS APPLY` to get the sum for each column.

```
SELECT     
    SUBJECT_ID, studentHours.hoursWorked AS HOURS, studentPoints.pointsEarned AS POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM       
    SOME_TABLES
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(someColumn) as hoursWorked
    FROM SOMETABLE2
    WHERE STUDENT_ID = 123
) studentHours
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(someColumn) as pointsEarned
    FROM SOME_POINTS_TABLE
    WHERE STUDENT_ID = 123
) studentPoints
WHERE SUBJECT_ID = 12
GROUP BY 
    SUBJECT_ID, SEMESTER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

With [sample table](http://pastebin.com/uV4FVZWM) query should look like this:

`WITH cte AS
(SELECT
    SUBJECT_ID, HOURS, POINTS, SEMESTER_ID
FROM
    SAMPLE_TABLE2
GROUP BY 
    HOURS, POINTS, SUBJECT_ID, SEMESTER_ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBJECT_ID,
    sum(Hours) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID, SUBJECT_ID) Hours,
    sum(Points) over (partition by SEMESTER_ID, SUBJECT_ID) Points,
    SEMESTER_ID
FROM cte`

The key was:
`sum(Hours)`**`over`**`(partition by SEMESTER_ID,`**`SUBJECT_ID`**`) hours`
and:
`GROUP BY HOURS, POINTS, SUBJECT_ID, SEMESTER_ID` inside `INNER QUERY`.

Thanks to @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it will help much, but the TOP clause typically doesn't require a parenthesis . **Edit: And for best practice, an ORDER BY clause is recommended when using the TOP clause.** You can also try ORDER BY along with LIMIT. That may help.

Comment: top(x) is perfectily valid. You need parenthesis if you put something else such as: top(@x) or top(select max(x) from table)

Comment: Huh. Just noticed, OP isn't using MySQL. Does he/she still need the parenthesis since he/she's not passing an expression?

Comment: when using a number, they both work fine: top 1 or top(1). This is for backward compatibility and parenthesis should be used.

Comment: Ah, I see. Shouldn't he use an ORDER BY clause in respect to the TOP clause?

Comment: yes it should. otherwise there is no garantee that it will always return the same row.